# Make dropdown menu go upwards if it is at the bottom of the browser window, automatic toggle between down and up, depending on position

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am getting problem in Dropdown that goes down but it should go up according to window size.i am getting this problem in Angular UI Grid. Please see [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/ankush456/t5tgfzof/1/) to understand better.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span2">
            <table class="table">
                <tr ng-repeat="row in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]">
                    <td> <a>{{row}}</a>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <!-- To create dropups instead of dropdowns i could add the class "dropup" to the li-element below. -->
                            <!-- But what I need is an inteligent mechanism that decides when to use dropdown and when to use dropup -->
                            <li class="dropdown"> <a class="btn-link dropdown-toggle">
                                <i class="icon-align-justify"></i>
                            </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li ng-repeat="menu in [1,2,3]"> <a class="btn-link">{{menu}}</a>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: make your dropdown container element absolute and parent element related position, will work.

Comment: I added already but still same thing is happening

Comment: It is in the bootstrap docs.... Search for `.dropup`

Comment: @epascarello - Can you please rescind the close / duplicate tag on this question. It isn't a duplicate, I think you misunderstood it. The qn is for an automatic toggle between down and up, depending on position, '.dropup' would be, at best, only a component in any correct answer.

Comment: @epascarello : Could you provide the answer for this question..it's not a duplicate one. The one marked as the duplicate of this quetion is actually different..it's just about how to render the dropdown up always but not based on it's position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to have to handle this yourself, it may be a little messy but I honestly I don't see how you can do it otherwise. I have modified your li tag to add a **class** (you can also use **id**) attribute to be able to reference it using jQuery (or plain javascript if you want to) and then added an **ng-class** to be able to dynamically assign either *dropdown* or *dropup*.

```
<li class="{{'row-' + row}}" ng-class="getClass(row)">
    <a class="btn-link dropdown-toggle"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="menu in [1,2,3]"> <a class="btn-link">{{menu}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now, inside your controller, you can create the **getClass** function to decide, based on the dropdown's position relative to the window, which class it should have.

```
var dropdownHeight = 140; // estimate/calculate the dropdown list's height manually
$scope.getClass = function (row) {
    if ($(window).height() - $('.row-' + row).position().top < dropdownHeight) {
        return 'dropup';
    }
    return 'dropdown';
};
```

You can play around with the values of the height until satisfied with the behavior, but keep in mind the you might want to add an event listener on window resize (and related events) to be able to recalculate the classes based on the new numbers.

Comment: There is no need for JavaScript when bootstrap supports it.

Comment: I see you put a duplicate flag on this question, I don't want to reinvent the wheel but I fail to see what class needs to be used for bootstrap to automatically decide if the dropdown needs to be drawn up or down.

Comment: Thanks Ghassen Louhaichi

Comment: You are most welcome.